# SOLR Custom Stemming Filter Spills Suffixes to Subsequent Tokens

Tags: solr, lucene, stemming

This is a rather unusual issue that I am facing while trying to implement my custom Stemming Filter for SOLR 4.x . The Last character/suffix of the first Token generated gets appended to the subsequent tokens in the stream after passing through my custom filter.

Please refer to the screenshot for reference,

[image]

**Field Type Definition:**

```
<fieldType name="text_hi_cust" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>

  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_hi.txt" />

  <filter class="com.rev.solr.utils.hindi.stemmer.HindiStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

**Field Definition:**

```
<field name="loc_hi_2" type="text_hi_cust" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Stemmer Filter Factory:**

```
public class HindiStemFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory{

public HindiStemFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
    super(args);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    if (!args.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameters: " + args);
    }
}

@Override
public TokenStream create(TokenStream ts) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new HindiStemFilter(ts);
}}
```

**Stemmer Filter:**

```
public final class HindiStemFilter extends TokenFilter {
private final CharTermAttribute termAttr;
private final KeywordAttribute keywordAttr;
private final HindiStemmer stemmer;
protected HindiStemFilter(TokenStream input) {
    super(input);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    termAttr = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    keywordAttr = addAttribute(KeywordAttribute.class);
    stemmer = new HindiStemmer();
}
@Override
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (input.incrementToken()) {
        if (!keywordAttr.isKeyword())
            termAttr.setLength(stemmer.stem(termAttr.buffer(),
                    termAttr.length())); 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**Hindi Stemmer**

```
public int stem(char buffer[], int len) throws IOException{
    loadDictionaries();     
    String input = new String(buffer);
    int rootLen = getRootlength(input.trim());//Returns the length of the root word.
    return rootLen;
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem and its solution. Probably not the best, but it works.

Problems observed:

1. The Input Buffer Stream when convert to string had around 7-8 white spaces. This was messing with the length manipulation.
2. Repopulate the same buffer using the new length.

public int stem(char buffer[], int len) throws IOException{

```
String input = new String(buffer);
int rootLen = getRootlength(input.trim());
for(int i=0;i<rootLen;i++){

    buffer[i] = input.charAt(i);
    return rootLen;
}
```

Hope this helps!